Embed resource on Windows only
I have a MAUI project for Android, iOS, MacOS and Windows.
I'd like to embed a heavy file (> 25 MB), but it's useful on Windows version only.
It seems that using FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync retrieves the asset files in Resources/Raw folder only. However, if I put my file here, it will be embedded on iOS, Android and MacOS versions too.
How can I embed my file on Windows only ? Is there a special place where I can put it, or maybe a way to exclude it from Android, iOS and MacOS platforms ?
Thank you for your help!

You can do this by changing the code in the csproj file. When you open the project's csproj file you will find:
     <ItemGroup>
            <!-- App Icon -->
            <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

            .....
            <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
            <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
      </ItemGroup>

And then just change the Resources\Raw\** to the Embed resource for all the platfroms. Then add the special file for only windows platform.
     <ItemGroup>
            <!-- App Icon -->
            <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

            .....
            <!-- the test.txt will add in all the platforms -->
            <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\test.txt" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
      </ItemGroup>

     <ItemGroup Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">
           <!-- the AboutAssets.txt will add in only windows platform -->
            <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\AboutAssets.txt" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
      </ItemGroup>


You are welcome. For more information, you can refer to the Raw assets in the .Net Maui.
